# Query to determine if a multiple-table entity matches multiple-table criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I work with accounts in a T-SQL database that have attributes distributed throughout multiple tables. Each account may be assigned a code depending if the attributes of that account match the ones necessary for the code. I'm trying to develop a query that can take a given account and a given code, determine if they are compatible, and return the values where they match and don't match. Let me give an example.

Say we have the following:

```
Table Person
(
    UniqueID
    , FirstName
    , LastName
    , FK_EyeColor
    , FK_HairColor
    , FK_Age
)

Table EyeColor
(
    PK_EyeColor
    , EyeColor
)

Table HairColor
(
    PK_HairColor
    , HairColor
)

Table Age
(
    PK_Age
    , Age
)
```

And a person with the following attributes:

```
UniqueID = 1
FirstName = 'John'
LastName = 'Doe'
FK_EyeColor = 3  -- Brown eyes
FK_HairColor = 4  -- Black hair
PK_Age = 19  -- 19 y/o
```

Now, let's say I have a category code that gets assigned to people with brown eyes and brown hair:

```
Table Categories
(
    PK_Categories
    , CategoryName
    , FK_EyeColor
    , FK_HairColor
)
```

What I'd like to do is specify a person and a category and determine if the person fits the category. Ideally, it'd return something like:

```
Person.UniqueID | FK_EyeColor | FK_HairColor | Qualifies for "Brown" category
              1 |           3 |            4 | No
              2 |           3 |            3 | Yes
```

What would be an efficient way to compare these table values? I'm having a hard time coming up with a good plan of attack for the coding component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with SQL like this:

```
select 
  p.UniqueID,
  p.FK_EyeColor,
  p.FK_HairColor,
  case
    when c.CategoryName = 'brown' 
    then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' 
  end as Brown_category
from person as p
left outer join categories as c
on p.FK_HairColor = c.FK_HairColor
and p.FK_EyeColor = c.FK_EyeColor
where c.CategoryName is not null
```

Which I have written in a working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3531d/1